Reaction of CH3NH2 (Excess) with NaNO2+HCl
I was told by my chemistry instructor that if we react excess CH3NH2 with NaNO2+HCl(source of HNO2), an ester is formed due to further dehydrogenation of methanol formed by HCl.Im having trouble understanding the reason behind this and whether if it is true.
Kindly help
Thanks!
I've already gone through a similar question asked on this platform but it doesn't answer my question.
